# Why is my web page requesting and getting a 404 for this Google Charts JS file?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-visualization

I have inherited an Angular 6 project that uses Google Charts. Specifically, it uses a package called ng2-google-charts. As far as I can tell, this is a package that tries to make Google Charts easy to use for Angular 2+. (Is this correct?)

When I load a page, I can see from the developer console that it retrieves files in this order:

https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js

https://www.gstatic.com/charts/45.2/loader.js

https://www.gstatic.com/charts/45.2/js/jsapi_compiled_undefined_module.js

The last one is not found (404 error). When I look in the code in the first loader.js, it says this, which I assume retrieves the second file:

```
d=I.f.H.from("https://www.gstatic.com/charts/%{version}/loader.js")
```

When I look in the code in the second loader.js, it says this, which I assume retrieves the third file:

```
compiled:R.f.H.from("https://www.gstatic.com/charts/%{version}/js/jsapi_compiled_%{package}_module.js")
```

So I assume that %{package} is undefined for some reason, and it's put it into the URL for the third file, which then makes the URL invalid. Why is this happening? The charts seem to be working fine in the application, as far as I can tell.

Comment: the third file should be the package requested by the load statement, at least one package should be requested -- somewhere in `ng2-google-charts`, do you see a call to --> `google.charts.load`? it should request a package such as --> `google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});` -- which would produce --> `https://www.gstatic.com/charts/46.2/js/jsapi_compiled_corechart_module.js`

Comment: There are a couple places in the ng2-google-charts code that say google.charts.load('45.2', initializer); But I think the most likely source of in the invalid URL is what I said in my original post: the line in the second loader.js file that says compiled:R.f.H.from("https://www.gstatic.com/charts/%{version}/js/jsapi_compiled_%{package}_module.js")

Comment: that's correct, and it's because a package is not being loaded...